# Template for stl container

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Inside the declaration of the class `Density`, I built these member function:

```
class Density {
public:
    template <typename Container>
    void printStream (Container<Point>::iterator lo, Container<Point>::iterator hi);
......
};
```

In the cpp file:

```
template <typename Container>
void Density::printStream (Container<Point>::iterator lo, Container<Point>::iterator hi)
{
...
}
```

But get these errors when trying to compile:

```
src/../include/density.hpp:166:23: error: 'Container' is not a template
src/../include/density.hpp:166:50: error: expected unqualified-id before 'lo'
src/../include/density.hpp:166:50: error: expected ')' before 'lo'
src/../include/density.hpp:166:50: error: expected initializer before 'lo'
src/density.cpp: In member function 'void Density::startAlgorithm()':
src/density.cpp:291:43: error: 'printStream' was not declared in this scope
src/density.cpp: At global scope:
src/density.cpp:327:28: error: 'Container' is not a template
src/density.cpp:327:55: error: expected unqualified-id before 'lo'
src/density.cpp:327:55: error: expected ')' before 'lo'
src/density.cpp:327:55: error: expected initializer before 'lo'
```

What should I modify?  And also, why, as I'd like to understand this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NB. As commented, you might not be aware of the implications that using templates has on the visibility of template definitions in the header files. Let me point you to the [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) entry for that: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/495056#495056)

---

Using a *template template argument*:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container>
void Density::printStream ()
{
    typename Container<Point>::iterator lo;
    typename Container<Point>::iterator hi;
}
```

What you are trying to do, seems to me to be impossible, since the iterator arguments are non-deducible context, so you'd end up explicitely specifying the container type anyways:

```
   density_instance.printStream<std::vector>(it1, it2);
```

Note, however, that's not really a problem, since you probably don't really care about the precise type of the container. The idiomatic way would be:

```
template <typename It>
    void printStream (It lo, It hi);
```

which you can freely call using

```
std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3 };
density_instance.printStream(begin(v), end(v));
```

But also with a non-class container, since the iterators are what matters:

```
const int a[] = { 1,2,3 };
density_instance.printStream(std::begin(a), std::end(b));
```

Comment: Is it really standard conform to use `...` and only provide one argument (i.e. omit the allocator argument)?

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh, good point. I'm going to "fix" that linking to the faq: **[A: Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/495056#495056)**

Comment: @celtschk I certainly hope so, since I don't think many people _always_ specify the allocator type. Now, I have a hunch you're probably on to the "things are not being deduced here" thing that I also addressed in the remainder of my answer :)

Comment: I think you forgot to remove `<std::vector>` from your last two examples.

Comment: The point is, in C++03, it would have seemed just as natural to use `template<template<typename T> class Container>` and expect it to work on `std::vector` because you can use it with just one argument. But that didn't work. Now, relying on default arguments being preserved by "..." seems to me to be quite unobvious; thus it's surprising that this should work while the more obvious thing doesn't. But then, it's of course not impossible (and it would be great if it did).

Comment: @celtschk Well, as per the standard, `std::vector` is declared as a class template with two "formal" type template arguments. So, if you wanted it to match without variadics, you'd need `template<template<typename,typename> class Container>`, but how would you match other containers that take another number of type template arguments (e.g. `std::priority_queue`)? I love variadics; they make _template template arguments_ slightly less useless than they used to be :)

Comment: @celtschk You're right: that `template<typename...> class` as a template template parameter matches `template<typename, typename> class vector;` as an argument is a special rule. Generally speaking I recommend avoiding template template parameters altogether as they are unflexible (e.g. even `template<typename...> class` won't accept `std::array`, as it involves a non-type template parameter) and the functionality they appear to provide can be reproduced in other ways (e.g. allocators have a mechanism to 'rebind' their template arguments, should they be class templates in the first place).

Comment: @not-sehe: Thank you! I'll use the second option with `<typename It>`.  I don't know why you said it's overkill, but I understand it and find it simpler.  And it's working.

Comment: @Luis I meant to say that what you were doing seemed like overkill, because it can be done much simpler :) I'll edit it to make it clearer.